# Duvida com linguagem sql DB2

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, db2

estou estudando Db2 e me deparei com o seguinte codigo

SELECT  * FROM PRODUTOS_VIEW WHERE PRODUTOS_VIEW.IDSECAO ***IN (:RA_IDSECAO)***

queria entender oque significa esse IN (:RA_IDSECAO) pois não encontrei documentação sobre isso.
agradeço se alguem que compreende esse tema, me responder.

Comment: Operador IN o :RA_IDSECAO deve ser um parâmetro , uma lista de "seções" talvez. https://www.ibmmainframer.com/db2-tutorial/db2-sql-in-notin-operator/

Answer (score -3):

IN (:RA_IDSECAO)
vários idsecao recebidos por um parâmetro de entrada